# Can I use an `sx` prop in a `styled` component

Tags: material-ui, sx

So my question really isn't should I, but rather can I.

If I opt to use `styled` components for my more common components then I style them once and export.

```
const MyBlueButton = styled('button')({
  backgroundColor: 'blue'
})
```

Great export that and I have a blue button.

I can also use `sx`

```
const MyBlueButton = (props) => {
  return <button sx={{backgroundColor: 'blue'}}>{props.children}</button>
}
```

My question is can I have both, one where I've already made my common component but then want to customize it just a bit unique for one use.

```
'components/buttons.jsx':

export const MyBlueButton = styled('button')({
  backgroundColor: 'blue'
})

--------

'FooBar.jsx':
import {MyBlueButton} from 'components/buttons'

const FooBar = (props) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <p>Some text</p>
      <MyBlueButton sx={{fontSize: '20px'}}>Large Blue Button</MyBlueButton>
    </div>
  )
}
```

I didn't find anything stating that you couldn't do it. I'm sure you quite possibly can, but can you, and what would be the expected order of css properties?

If I have a styled component with a matching css property in the sx prop would sx win since it's closer to the render? Should I have to worry about injection order with the `StyledEngineProvider`?

I'm really just hoping I can use a healthy mix of both styled components and one off sx modifications.

Answer (score 1):

I went ahead and made a codesand box to test my idea and it does work to combine both `styled` wrappers and `sx` props.

Again probably not for everyday use, but it's nice to know it is possible.

CodeSandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/keen-roman-s6i7l?file=/src/App.tsx

Answer (score 0):

I have been into such issue;
the way I had to implement the sx props to be passed before passing the component to styled engine was neglecting the props:

`const AutoComplete = withThemeProvider(styled(Autocomplete)(autoCompleteStyles));`

and when to use it, it gets neglected
 `<Autocomplete sx={neglectedProps}>`

Comment: is there a possbile way to pass them while invoking the styled HOC?